# Databind a listbox - one object member needs special processing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

```xml
<ListBox Name="DisplayItemListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ListBoxItem  >
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Response}"  />
             <Button Width="50" Height="50" Content="Remove" Click="Request_Remove_Click"/>
             <Image Name="MyImage" Width="50" Height="50"  />
             </StackPanel>
       </ListBoxItem>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

I bind in codebehind like this:

```
DisplayItemListBox.ItemsSource = (List<MyObject>) MyObjectList;
```

MyObject has a binary Photo attribute that I need to convert to a BitmapImage in code behind.  I need to modify my XAML in such a way that, when the ListBoxItems are first initialized with data, a function is hit that has access to both the ListBoxItem's MyObject and it's MyImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of ValueConverters? These allow you to convert a property within the binding process. The following example show how to convert a URI into a BitmapImage which you can use as a Source for an Image element:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/SilverlightWPFandXAML/03d69c15-172b-4098-bb90-5119f9bdac24/silverlight-ivalueconverter-for-image-urls.aspx

You should be able to use something similar.